# How to find duplicate filenames (recursively) in a given directory? BASH

Tags: bash, duplicates, filenames

I need to find every duplicate filenames in a given dir tree. I dont know, what dir tree user will give as a script argument, so I dont know the directory hierarchy. I tried this:

```
#!/bin/sh
find -type f | while IFS= read vo
do
echo `basename "$vo"`
done
```

but thats not really what I want. It finds only one duplicate and then ends, even, if there are more duplicate filenames, also - it doesnt print a whole path (prints only a filename) and duplicate count. I wanted to do something similar to this command:

```
find DIRNAME | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' | sort | uniq -c | grep -v " 1 "
```

but it doenst work for me, dont know why. Even if I have a duplicates, it prints nothing.
I use Xubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here is another solution (based on the suggestion by @jim-mcnamara) without awk:

**Solution 1**

```
#!/bin/sh 
dirname=/path/to/directory
find $dirname -type f | sed 's_.*/__' | sort|  uniq -d| 
while read fileName
do
find $dirname -type f | grep "$fileName"
done
```

However, you have to do the same search twice. This can become very slow if you have to search a lot of data. Saving the "find" results in a temporary file might give a better performance.

**Solution 2 (with temporary file)**

```
#!/bin/sh 
dirname=/path/to/directory
tempfile=myTempfileName
find $dirname -type f  > $tempfile
cat $tempfile | sed 's_.*/__' | sort |  uniq -d| 
while read fileName
do
 grep "/$fileName" $tempfile
done
#rm -f $tempfile
```

Since you might not want to write a temp file on the harddrive in some cases, you can choose the method which fits your needs. 
Both examples print out the full path of the file.

Bonus question here: Is it possible to save the whole output of the find command as a list to a variable?

Comment: You can use grep -f to get rid of the while and simplify it a bit: cat $tempfile | sed 's_.*/__' | sort |  uniq -d| grep -f $tempfile

Comment: Minor error in Solution 1 may lead to false positives. You'd better write the last find as: find $dirname -type f | grep "^${fileName}$"

Comment: How could I change solution 2 so that the first file found is not added to the temporary file, only the duplicates that are found second?

Comment: MacOs : find: -printf: unknown primary or operator

Answer (score 25):

Yes this is a really old question.
But all those loops and temporary files seem a bit cumbersome.

### Here's my 1-line answer:

```
find /PATH/TO/FILES -type f -printf '%p/ %f\n' | sort -k2 | uniq -f1 --all-repeated=separate
```

**It has its limitations due to `uniq` and `sort`:**

- no whitespace (space, tab) in filename (will be interpreted as new field by `uniq` and `sort`)
- needs file name printed as last field delimited by space (`uniq` doesn't support comparing only 1 *field* and is inflexible with field delimiters)

But it is quite flexible regarding its output thanks to `find -printf` and  works well for me. Also seems to be what @yak tried to achieve originally.

**Demonstrating some of the options you have with this:**

```
find  /PATH/TO/FILES -type f -printf 'size: %s bytes, modified at: %t, path: %h/, file name: %f\n' | sort -k15 | uniq -f14 --all-repeated=prepend
```

Also there are options in `sort` and `uniq` to ignore case (as the topic opener intended to achieve by piping through `tr`). Look them up using `man uniq` or `man sort`.

Comment: `/usr/share/fslint/fslint/findsn /path/to/files`

But I like your one-liner better for its flexibility.

Answer (score 8):

```
#!/bin/sh
dirname=/path/to/check
find $dirname -type f | 
while read vo
do
  echo `basename "$vo"`
done | awk '{arr[$0]++; next} END{for (i in arr){if(arr[i]>1){print i}}}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it without `awk`? Thanks anyway :)

Comment: You can do it with any language that supports associative arrays (or hashing is another name) - perl is an example.  bash 4 has support for associative arrays as well.

Comment: So you say that only-bash solution isnt possible? I mean, without sed, awk, perl, python, etc. just pure bash?

Comment: by the way, this solution only tells you the filename, without the path where they are. I thought that was a requirement

Comment: @ElisianoPetrini: ops, thanks, you're right. I need a full path. Question is open again.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

file=`mktemp /tmp/duplicates.XXXXX` || { echo "Error creating tmp file"; exit 1; }
find $1 -type f |sort >  $file
awk -F/ '{print tolower($NF)}' $file |
        uniq -c|
        awk '$1>1 { sub(/^[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+/,""); print }'| 
        while read line;
                do grep -i "$line" $file;
        done

rm $file
```

And it also work with spaces in filenames. Here's a simple test (the first argument is the directory):

```
./duplicates.sh ./test
./test/2/INC 255286
./test/INC 255286
```

Answer (score 2):

One "find" command only:

```
lst=$( find . -type f )
echo "$lst" | rev | cut -f 1 -d/ | rev | sort -f | uniq -i | while read f; do
   names=$( echo "$lst" | grep -i -- "/$f$" )
   n=$( echo "$names" | wc -l )
   [ $n -gt 1 ] && echo -e "Duplicates found ($n):\n$names"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution writes one temporary file to a temporary directory for every unique filename found.  In the temporary file, I write the path where I first found the unique filename, so that I can output it later.  So, I create a lot more files that other posted solutions.  But, it was something I could understand.

Following is the script, named `fndupe`.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create a temp directory to contain placeholder files.
tmp_dir=`mktemp -d`

# Get paths of files to test from standard input.
while read p; do
  fname=$(basename "$p")
  tmp_path=$tmp_dir/$fname
  if [[ -e $tmp_path ]]; then
    q=`cat "$tmp_path"`
    echo "duplicate: $p"
    echo "    first: $q"
  else
    echo $p > "$tmp_path" 
  fi
done

exit
```

Following is an example of using the script.

```
$ find . -name '*.tif' | fndupe
```

Following is example output when the script finds duplicate filenames.

```
duplicate: a/b/extra/gobble.tif
    first: a/b/gobble.tif
```

Tested with Bash version: `GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my contribution (this just searches for a specific file type, pdfs in this case) but it does so recursively:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

find . -type f | while read filename; do
    filename=$(basename -- "$filename")
    extension="${filename##*.}"
    if [[ $extension == "pdf" ]]; then
        fileNameCount=`find . -iname "$filename" | wc -l`
        if [[ $fileNameCount -gt 1 ]]; then
            echo "File Name: $filename, count: $fileNameCount"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon this interesting case lately. Sharing my solution here even the question is long outdated.

### **Using join , no grep,awk,python,sed,perl,etc. :**

```
#!/bin/sh
list=$(mktemp)
find PATH/TO/DIR/ -type f -printf '%f\t%p\n' | sort -f >$list
cut -d\^I -f1 <$list | uniq -d -i | join -i -t\^I - $list
rm $list
```

Quick notes:

- ^I in command above stands for the tab character. Replace in actual command.
- Spaces in file names are supported.
- File names must not contain tabs or newlines characters.
- Performance seems very good. Tested on a large directory tree with several thousand files and the results were almost instant.
- The comparisons are done case-insensitively. Case-sensitiveness can be achieved by removal of sort "-f" and uniq+join "-i" options.

#### Example:

Directory tree:

```
a/f1
a/f2
a/f3
b/f2
c/f2
c/f3
```

Output:

```
f2  a/f2
f2  b/f2
f2  c/f2
f3  a/f3
f3  c/f3
```