# Find files with same name but different content

Tags: python, linux, sed

I need to find files with the same name but different content in a linux folder structure with a lot of files.

Something like this does the job partially, how do i eliminate files with different content?

```
#!/bin/sh 
dirname=/path/to/directory
find $dirname -type f | sed 's_.*/__' | sort|  uniq -d| 
while read fileName
do
find $dirname -type f | grep "$fileName"
done
```

([How to find duplicate filenames (recursively) in a given directory? BASH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276595/how-to-find-duplicate-filenames-recursively-in-a-given-directory-bash))

Thanks so much !

Comment: When you have, say, 3 files all named `spam.txt`, and they all have different content, which 2 do you want to eliminate?

Comment: Are you looking for python code to do this?

Comment: Whatever rule you come up with, you obviously need some code that applies that rule… unless the rule really is "I don't care, just kill two of them and keep the other". In that case, this is pretty easy. You've got a list of duplicate files. You want to remove all but one, chosen arbitrarily. So just pop the first one off the list, and remove all the rest.

Comment: If the rule is, say, "keep the oldest one", then you'll need to either get the list sorted by time in the first place (which would be easier if you just did a `find` by `-name` instead of a `find` of everything and then `grep` for the name…), or just `stat` each file in a loop and remove the oldest one from the list. (I think that would be a lot easier in Python than in bash…)

Comment: Thanks for the quick comments. @abarnert, I want to to just list them and eliminate them myself. Eric anything is good.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense—but edit your question to actually say that. Also, you still haven't answered Eric Renouf's question. You've tagged this with Python, but given us bash code. Which one do you actually want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question is, how can you determine whether two files have the same content?

One obviously possibility is to read (or mmap) both files and compare them a block at a time. On some platforms, a `stat` is a lot faster than a `read`, so you may want to first compare sizes. And there are other optimizations that might be useful, depending on what you're actually doing (e.g., if you're going to run this thousands of times, and most of the files are the same every time, you could hash them and cache the hashes, and only check the actual files when the hashes match). But I doubt you're too worried about that kind of performance tweak if your existing code is acceptable (since it searches the whole tree once for every file in the tree), so let's just do the simplest thing.

Here's one way to do it in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

def readfile(path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        return f.read()

contents = [readfile(fname) for fname in sys.argv[1:]]
sys.exit(all(content == contents[0] for content in contents[1:]))
```

This will exit with code 1 if all files are identical, code 0 if any pair of files are different. So, save this as `allequal.py`, make it executable, and your bash code can just run `allequal.py` on the results of that `grep`, and use the exit value (e.g., via `$?`) to decide whether to print those results for you.

Comment: isn't using a `hashlib` in python an easier way to compare files than comparing them block-by-block ?

Comment: @fixxxer: Not really. If you don't care about reading the entire file, `f.read()` is even simpler than anything you can do with `hashlib`. If you want to exit early, reading block by block is still simpler than hashing block by block. I suppose in the case where you don't mind wasting the time reading the whole file, but do mind wasting the RAM, hashing might be simpler than mmapping, but otherwise, when would it make things easier?

Comment: If you have a list of file, which you want to match a new file against to test for duplicates, then perhaps its useful ? Matching a file against multiple others would be wasteful (not something that the OP asked for, but asking generally)

Comment: @fixxxer: Sure, hashes are a great optimization if, say, you want to repeat this job over and over every time you have a few new files without having to re-read all of the old files. But still not _simpler_ (especially because you still need to read the files if the hashes match, to deal with collisions); it's more complicated, but probably worth it for the efficiency gain.

Comment: @fixxxer: But, again, anyone who really cares about efficiency wouldn't have written that quadratic search over his tree in the first place. In fact, now that I think about it, I shouldn't have included the block-by-block optimization in the first place; let me re-edit.

Comment: I think I've been tip-toeing around collisions in places where I've used hashing as a way to summarise files on a computer, here : https://github.com/torsionpeg/filer

Comment: @abarnert: Is there anything similarly (simple) for `Python 2.x`?

Comment: @l'L'l: Well, that code does require the `all` function and generator expressions, but I think those were added in 2.4 and 2.3. So, just change the `python3` to `python` in the shbang line and it should just work.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem as described in the question. In a large directory tree, some files have the same name and either same content or different content. The ones where the content differs need human attention to decide how to fix the situation in each case. I need to create a list of these files to guide the person doing this.

The code in the question and the code in the abernet's response are both helpful. Here is how one would combine both: Store the python code from abernet's response in some file, e.g. /usr/local/bin/do_these_files_have_different_content:

```
sudo tee /usr/local/bin/do_these_files_have_different_content <<EOF
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

def readfile(path):
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        return f.read()

contents = [readfile(fname) for fname in sys.argv[1:]]
sys.exit(all(content == contents[0] for content in contents[1:]))
EOF

sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/do_these_files_have_different_content
```

Then extend the bash code from Illusionist's question to call this program when needed, and react on its outcome:

```
#!/bin/sh 
dirname=$1
find $dirname -type f | sed 's_.*/__' | sort|  uniq -d| 
while read fileName
do
if do_these_files_have_different_content $(find $dirname -type f | grep "$fileName")
then find $dirname -type f | grep "$fileName"
     echo
fi
done
```

This will write to stdout the paths of all files with same name but different content. Groups of files with same name but different content are separated by empty lines. I store the shell script in /usr/local/bin/find_files_with_same_name_but_different_content and invoke it as

```
find_files_with_same_name_but_different_content /path/to/my/storage/directory
```